# Faster print of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a 3D large Matrix, the first index (`x`) represents frequency and the second and third indexes (`y` and `z`) are the indexes of the data. I want to print the data for each index for all the frequencies, then print a `|` char and a new line char. I do this in the following way:

```
% S is a 3D matrix of size (x,y,z), where y=z and x>>y
N=size(S,2);
MM=real(S);
for mi=1:N
    for mj=1:N
        fprintf(fid,"%.16g ",MM(:,mi,mj));
        fprintf(fid,"|\n");
    end
end
```

But for large matrices this is very slow. Is there a way to speed up the process?

This is done in octave, which means that a Matlab solution will work as well.

Comment: You need to look at what is actually taking the time, when you do the print which part is the slow bit? For example certain consoles throttle the scrolling rate.

Comment: @TimB, I don't understand, there is only one part to the code I presented.

Comment: Is your matrix S of (N,N,N) size? you use `N=size(S,2)` for 2nd and 3rd dimension.

Comment: But behind the scenes the computer is doing a lot of things. When you do fprintf its putting out the output somewhere and there are a number of steps to doing that. For example if its printing to std out on a windows computer then the CMD prompt will not let you scroll at more than a certain speed and your program will spend a lot of time waiting. If it is sending data over a network that might be slow. Even writing to a local disk is slower than to local memory, etc.

Comment: Fundamentally you have x*y*z items, which is a number which will grow very large very fast. You need to either print less data or you need to make that printing process faster.

Comment: @TimB, this works over Linux, the script writes into `stdout` but the main flow catches this, so it's piped into another program. The question is: "is there a way to use less loops here?"

Comment: Fundamentally you have X*Y*Z data points so it doesn't matter how you arrange the loops over them - you still have to print out X*Y*Z data points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your input data correct, your loop is equivalent to:

```
fprintf(fid,[repmat('%.16g ',1,size(S,1)) '|\n'],permute(real(S),[1,3,2]));
```

`fprintf` starts over using the format  string when it reaches the end. The permute is necessary to preserve the order from your code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a general approach to speed things up:

1. Calculate everything you want to calculate, store each result as a number or a string
2. Print the result to file in 1 go

Comment: How to print the result in 1 go?

Answer (score -1):

```
m=zeros(3,4,5);
[x,y,z]=size(m);
for k=1:x
    for l=1:y
        dlmwrite('D:\test.txt',m(k,l,:),'-append','delimiter',' ','newline','pc');
    end
    dlmwrite('D:\test.txt',[' '],'-append','newline','pc');
end
```